# Finding another case manager's cases

Tags: civicase, advanced-search

Is there a way of using advanced search to find another case manager's cases? I find the reports really complicated but would like to find another person's cases so I can update the notes. It's really easy to find mine as I just search my cases only. Is there an easy way to search for someone else's cases too? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to search - advanced search.
2. In the dropdown where it says "display results as" choose "Cases".
3. Expand the relationships section.
4. For relationship type choose the case manager type (e.g. "homeless services coordinator is").
5. For target contact put the name or partial name of the manager.
6. Click search.

Another way is:

1. Go to the manager's contact record.
2. On their relationships tab look for the manager type (e.g. "homeless services coordinator is").
3. On the far right under the "More" link it will say "Manage case #7", and you can click that to go to that case.